How to append records to a json object file in bash
I need to loop through a dictionary and append records to a json object file option.json
the code I have is
for K in "${!MYMAP[@]}"; do 
    opt="{
        \"OptionName\":\"${K}\",
        \"Value\":\"${MYMAP[$K]}\"
        },"
    echo $opt >> option.json
done 

But this produce option.json as below
{
    "OptionName": "name",
    "Value": "test"
},
{
    "OptionName": "age",
    "Value": "13"
}

How do i make the option.json a json object and appending each {} inside the object, so my option.json would look like below
[
    {
        "OptionName": "name",
        "Value": "test"
    },
    {
        "OptionName": "age",
        "Value": "13"
    }
]


Note that using string concatenation to generate structured data is error-prone -- as soon as your value has characters that need to be escaped to be valid JSON you'll start generating invalid syntax as output. Far better to use a tool like jq that understands JSON syntax and can do escaping on your behalf.

If you omit the trailing comma in the initial production, you get a stream of inputs that jq can collect into an array using the --slurp (or -s) flag:
for k in "${!mymap[@]}"; do 
  opt="{\"OptionName\":\"${k}\", \"Value\":\"${mymap[$k]}\"}"
  echo "$opt"                            # no comma here --^
done | jq -s . > option.json

However, you can also have jq do the JSON composition in the first place, guaranteeing valid JSON encoding even with challenging values (such as double quotes, etc.). For example, I'd use the --args option to import the bash array's keys and values as positional parameters, and the $ARGS builtin to access them:
declare -A mymap=([name]="test" [age]="13")

jq -n '
  $ARGS.positional | [_nwise(length/2)] | transpose
  | map({OptionName: first, Value: last})
' --args "${!mymap[@]}" "${mymap[@]}" > option.json

As @oguz pointed out, newer versions of bash can also expand arrays to their keys and values in our desired alternating order by using "${mymap[@]@k}". The full jq filter would then just read:
jq -n '$ARGS.positional | [_nwise(2) | {OptionName: first, Value: last}]' \
  --args "${mymap[@]@k}"


Newer versions of bash support "${mymap[@]@k}", which eliminates the need to transpose.

@oguz That's a good improvement, thank you.

That feature was apparently added in bash 5.1 (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366581/bash-associative-array-printing)

@peak According to this Bash changelog, @K (all pairs quoted in one word) was added in 5.1 (see 5.1.hh), but @k (each item as separate words, which is used here) was added in 5.2 (see 5.2.t)

Now @pmf if i want to add a third attributes with below option
jq -n '   $ARGS.positional | [_nwise(length/2)] | transpose   | map({OptionName: first, Value: last}) ' --args "${!mymap[@]}" "${mymap[@]}" > option.json how do I do the mapping part , i am new to jq, so not sure how to make  map({OptionName: first, Value: last}) to  map({NewAttribute: first, OptionName: second???, Value: last}) the NewAttribute is not part of the mymap instead it is just a static value

i tried to use nth(1) as below
declare -A mymap=([name]="test" [age]="13")
jq -n '   $ARGS.positional | [_nwise(length/3)] | transpose   | map({NewAttributes: first, OptionName: nth(1), Value: last}) ' --args "test" "${!MYMAP[@]}" "${MYMAP[@]}" > option.json but the out put result is wrong in the second element
[   {     "NewAttributes": "test",     "OptionName": "name",     "Value": "test"   },   {     "NewAttributes": "age",     "OptionName": "13",     "Value": null   } ]

i think i figured by just hard code the new attributes in the map
map({"NewAttributes": "NewValue", OptionName: first, Value: last})

@tanfei12345 For a static value, try jq -n '… {NewAttributes: "NewValue", OptionName: first, Value: last} …' --args …. To import it from the shell, try jq -n '… {$NewAttributes, OptionName: first, Value: last} …' --arg NewAttributes "NewValue" --args …. Also, have a look at the manual. The options --arg and --args are explained under Invoking jq.

Sure it's better to use jq if you work with json but in case when jq is not available printf can be used, like this:
declare -A arr=([key1]=val1 [key2]=val2)

items=$(
    for key in "${!arr[@]}"; {
        val=${arr[$key]}
        printf '{"%s": "%s"},\n' "$key" "$val"
    }
)

echo "[${items%,*}]"
[{"key2": "val2"},
{"key1": "val1"}]

Here is I'm using jq to validate the result:
$ echo "[${items%,*}]" | jq
[
  {
    "key2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "key1": "val1"
  }
]

Note this syntax ${items%,*} it will print $items without last comma which is crucial for json.
But yes, some tricky values like the one from comments may ruin everything and must be worked around:
declare -A arr=([key1]=val1 [key2]=val2 [key3]='foo "bar \ bar"')

items=$(
    for key in ${!arr[@]}; {
        printf -vval -- '%q' "${arr[$key]}"
        printf -vkey -- '%q'       "$key"
        printf '{"%s": "%s"},\n'  "${key//'\ '/ }" "${val//'\ '/ }"
    }
)

echo "[${items%,*}]" | jq
[
  {
    "key2": "val2"
  },
  {
    "key3": "foo \"bar \\ bar\""
  },
  {
    "key1": "val1"
  }
]


Until you get a value like arr[key3]='foo "bar \ bar"', then you have invalid JSON

A reimplementation of Ivan's solution that preserves your formatting -
$: mymap=( [name]=test [age]=13 )
$: fmt='%s  {\n    "OptionName": "%s",\n    "Value": "%s"\n  }'
$: for k in ${!mymap[@]}; do printf -v list "$fmt" "${list:+$list,$'\n'}" "$k" "${mymap[$k]}"; done
$: printf '[\n%s\n]\n' "$list"
[
  {
    "OptionName": "age",
    "Value": "13"
  },
  {
    "OptionName": "name",
    "Value": "test"
  }
]


But I point again to Glenn's comment - it's easy for odd data to break.
